# Ctrl+A is not working in firefox on input box if having some validations

Tags: javascript, firefox

I already found some relevant questions and its solutions on stackoverflow but none of the solutions worked for me. So, this is my exact problem :

> I have a payment form having several input box and offcourse some
>   validations on some of the input boxes. Ctrl+A/Ctrl+a is not working
>   on input box on which some validations are applied otherwise its
>   working fine. This is happening only in mozilla firefox but working
>   fine in chrome.

```
function isAllowedKey(event) {
    var allowed = false;
    if ( (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 9 || event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 39)  || (event.keyCode === 65 || event.keyCode === 97) && (event.ctrlKey === true) ) {
        allowed = true;
    } 
    return allowed;
}
```

Comment: already tried many solutions from different sources but nothing worked.

Comment: For me, the `Ctrl` key code is 17. You should add that to your list. Also, since `event.ctrlKey` is a boolean, `event.ctrlKey === true` is the same as `event.ctrlKey`

Comment: Off topic for the question, but you could just do `return ((event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 9 ... ) && (event.ctrlKey === true) )`. No need to assign a variable to hold the answer

Comment: On a side note, if you allow Ctrl + a, you might want to allow other shortcuts like Ctrl [+ or /] Shift + arrow keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Seblor, after trying your suggestions in different way I came up with a solution I wanted and violla, its working absolutely fine in allmost all browsers like chrome, firefox, IE9, Microsoft Edge.
The problem I was facing is that alraedy a lot of validations are apllied on input boxes because of which in firefox (Ctrl+a/Ctrl+A) was not working.
Below is the working function :

```
function isAllowedKey(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 9 || event.keyCode === 37 || 
        event.keyCode === 39 || event.ctrlKey === true) {
            return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```